Why is my .bbl file wrong when the bibliography is generated okay on the pdf?
I have been asked by a Journal to include all references on the main .tex file. I have generated a .bbl file using biblatex, biber etc:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
...
Other packages & macros
...
article text, figures etc..
...
\printbibliography[type=article]

This produces the correct references section with all the correct citations once I compile. However, the .bbl file generated by Overleaf contains the following:
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 3.2 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{none/global//global/global}
    \entry{seki_density_2018}{article}{}
      \name{author}{9}{}{%
        {{hash=e0e9862ec41f00011f2fc99716fde6a3}{%
           family={Seki},
           familyi={S\bibinitperiod},
           given={Shiro},
           giveni={S\bibinitperiod}}}%
        {{hash=a95ad55f9ffdfe1e39ccc91112620f2a}{%}
...
...

Which is clearly not conventional .bbl file contents I need to copy to the main .tex
Any idea why this might be the case?

You probably think of a typical bibtex file, not biblatex.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz If this is the correct format, why can I not directly copy the contents of the .bbl into the main .tex without the recompilation failing?

... a bibtex file just contains a simple  thebibliography environment. A bibtex file can be copied to the document without problems. A biblatex file is more complex.

I am following the steps in the following:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/The_journal_says_%22don%27t_use_BibTeX%3B_paste_the_contents_of_the_.bbl_file_into_the_.tex_file%22._How_do_I_do_this_on_Overleaf%3F

These instructions are for bibtex, not biblatex.

Have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530638/36296 might help

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you so much for your help. I hadn't realised biblatex and bibtex were so different/incompatible. I then spent an hour trying to recompile the project with loads of errors (I just needed to recompile from scratch). Bed time for me.
